# Convergence of Lebesgue integral with negative part finite

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(f_{n})_{n}$ a sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_{n}<f_{n+1}$. Also $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{k}^-dm < \infty$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}dm=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}dm.$$

I think write this like a growing sequence for use the monotone Lebesgue theorem, some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the limit exists almost-everywhere (otherwise the question doesn't even make sense), you basically spelled out the answer.

Without loss of generality, the negative part of $f_0$ is integrable (we can always forget finitely many elements of the sequence). Put $g_n=f_n+(f_0^-)$. Then $g_n$ are integrable, positive and increasing, so by monotone convergence
$$\int f_n+\int f_0^-=\int g_n\to \int\lim g_n=\int(\lim f_n+f_0^-)=\int\lim f_n+\int f_0^-$$
from which you immediately get the result.

Comment: The pointwise limit of an increasing sequence of functions always exists in the extended reals.

Comment: You can use `\left(` and `\right)` to adjust parenthesis size.

Comment: M. Greinecker: you're right. It still makes sense, because all the functions considered are (mostly) positive. Still, I hesitate to write an integral of a function infinite on a big set.

Comment: did: I know, but doing that wouldn't improve readability much in this case, and would make the expression two-line, which would be bad. Instead, I changed the notation somewhat -- should be prettier now.